# How to write the JAXB object that has attribute and value

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

Here's my intended XML structure

```
<Outer type="good" id="1">
  <Uid>123</Uid>
  <Name>Myself</Name>
  <Inner type="bad">This Value</Inner>
</Outer>
```

Here's my Object.

```
@XmlAccessorType(XMLAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name="Outer", propOrder = {
  "uid"
  "name"
  "inner"
})
public class Outer{
  @XmlElement(name = "Uid")
  protected String uid;
  @XmlElement(name = "Name")
  protected String name;
  @XmlElement(name = "Inner")
  protected Inner inner;

  public static class Inner{
    @XmlAttribute
    private String type;
    @XmlValue
    private String value;

    //setters & getters for both
  }

  //setters & getters for all the elements
}
```

Now in my class I am doing

```
Outer o = new Outer();
o.setUid/ID/Type/Name() ; //all the setter
Inner i - new Inner();
i.setValue("This Value");
i.setType("bad");
```

When Irun this i am getting

```
If a class has @XmlElement property, it cannot have @XmlValue property.
```

And

```
Class has two properties of the same name "type" (This one is for the Source class)
```

And

```
Class has two properties of the same name "value" (This one is for Source class too)
```

What is happening, and what I can I do rectify this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, JAXB threats both fields (due to annotations) and both pairs of get/set (due to default accessor type) as properties. So you class `Inner` has 4 properties.

Please, add own accessor type for `Inner` class

```
   @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
   public static class Inner
   {
```

Or annotate properties instead of fields

```
   public static class Inner
   {

      private String type;


      private String value;

      @XmlAttribute
      public String getType()
      {
         return type;
      }
      // setter setType

      @XmlValue
      public String getValue()
      {
         return value;
      }   
      // setter setValue
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Add XmlRootElement annotation to the Outer class, besides of that it shoud work.

```
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "Outer", propOrder = {"uid", "name", "inner"})
public static class Outer {
```

Comment: Actually, outside an Outer, there's another element, that contains the XMLRootElement. I am trying to add the Inner one to this structure, and that is causing the problem.

Comment: I see, then maybe you should post that too!

Comment: apparently, I need to annotate the static Inner class with @XmlAccessorType(XMLAccessType.FIELD) XMLType(name="",propOrder = {"value"}